# Is it possible to draw the center of a given circle using a compass only?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> Can you construct the center of a given circle using a compass only. If the answer is yes, how?

I've had this question for a while, the only thing I was able to do is find a line containing the center. As a matter of fact, take $A,B$ two distinct arbitrary points of the circle. Draw the circle with radius $AB$ and center $A$, and let it cut the given circle in a point $C≠B$. Construct two circles, both with radius $BC$, one with center $C$ and one with center $B$. Intersect them in a point $D$. Thus $(AD)$ is the perpendicular bisector of $[BC]$, and therefore, contains the center of the given circle. This is what I got, and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Every construction that can be done with straightedge and compass can be done with compass alone, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#:~:text=More%20formally%2C%20the%20only%20permissible,single%20circle%20and%20its%20center.) or [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass.shtml).

Comment: If it contains the center, it is a diameter. The center lies at its midpoint.

Comment: @eyeballfrog How would you find the midpoint?

Comment: With $AD$, you can construct the point $E$ on the circle on line $AD$, then find points $F$,$G$ on the perpendicular bisector using the regular construction. Then find the intersection of $AE$ and $FG$ to get the center $H$. The construction of $E$ and $H$ is possible according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem#Intersection_of_two_non-parallel_lines_(construction_#3)), though it looks pretty obnoxious. There may be a less involved way.

Comment: @lulu That answers my question, thanks!

Comment: You could also do the whole process twice and the center will be the intersection of the two final segments.